# Golang not producing error when decoding "{}" body into struct

Tags: json, http, go

In a rest api, when the body is set to "{}", the json Decoder will not generate an error. This makes it necessary to check if the target struct is still `nil`.

I need to check if the library is supposed to work like this, or if this is an issue with it.

```
// Client Side this request
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "url", strings.NewReader("{}") )

// Curl equivalent: 
curl -X POST -d '{}' http://api:8080/r/primitives/multiply

// Server side
type Operands struct {
    Values []float64 `json:"Values"`
}

func handler(req *http.Request, res *http.Response) (string, error) {
    operands := Operands{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&operands)
    if err != nil {
        res.StatusCode = 400
        res.Status = http.StatusText(res.StatusCode)
        http.StatusText(res.StatusCode)
        return "", err
    }
     operands.Values[0] // It will fail here.
}
```

Edit 1: The decoder works fine with and empty body "" with the error being generated, and works fine with a correct body like this one: `{"Values" : [ 5.0 , 2.0 ]}`
Edit 2: The issue here is that with a "{}" body, it will not return an error when decoding, instead it will keep the target struct as nil.

Comment: you are trying to read an emoty json construct,  that might be why it panics

Comment: Something else is the issue. The given JSON body decodes into the given struct just fine: https://play.golang.org/p/-0chO37DxxR

Comment: @JimB that is probably an issue, but does not cause the given error, it still decodes fine: https://play.golang.org/p/uA2x7F7i9dA

Comment: Thank you for pointing that @JimB. But the function works fine with valid inputs, and also with totally empty inputs.

Comment: Then where is the actual panic? Decoding an empty body will obviously not return any data, so you can't index the slice without checking it's length.

Comment: @JimB I figured the issue was no exactly where I thought. I just edited the post accordingly.

Comment: The updated code shows that @JimB's last comment has it on the nose - you're trying to index into an empty slice, hence the panic, telling you that you're trying to access a slice index that's out of bounds (which would be any index in an empty slice). What behavior were you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting it to produce an error when decoding “{}” into a struct. @Adrian

Comment: If you read the `encoding/json` documentation, you'll find it explains that neither missing fields nor unexpected fields will cause decoding to fail. Fields missing from the JSON will yield zero values in the result, while unexpected fields in the JSON will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is just an empty Json object, and it will decode fine to your `Operands`struct, as the struct is not required to have anything in the `Operands` array.

You need to validate that yourself, e.g.

```
err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&operands)
if err != nil || len(operands.Values) == 0{
```